# Focus cannot be set on ui-ace in an Excel add-in

Tags: jquery, angularjs-directive, focus, office-js, ace-editor

(* I re-launch an old question which is still unsolved *)

I am making an Excel add-in by mean-stack. I want to make a task page that contains a JavaScript-based source editor. I have tried ui-codemirror and [ui-ace](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace), there is a problem in Excel for Windows: if we click on Excel, then click back to the editor area, the focus cannot be set in the editor area, thus the content is NOT editable.

Here is a [code](https://jsbin.com/zuwicoqeve/3/edit?html,output) with `ui-ace`, it works well in a browser. However, when we wrap the same code into an Excel add-in, each time we click on Excel then click back to the editor area, we see `mousedown`, `focusset`, `mousedown` and `focusset`. And we cannot find the focus, the content is NOT editable.

So does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your call to focus $timeout with something like:

```
$timeout( { element.focus() }, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you... I tried `$timeout`, it did not help at all. I then tried `$interval(function () { e.currentTarget.env.editor.focus() }, 0)`, it worked for most of the time, but sometimes we may see another focus flashing above...

Comment: $interval will repeat the call. You don't really want that. I would experiment with different delays and see if you can get $timeout to work. I think that's ultimately going to be the solution.

Comment: OK... you may need to test it under Excel for Windows, hope you have the toolset...